# Does iOS push notification payload convert long integers into scientific notation?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

When I create a PN payload with a long variable like 1088337848880612568, it seem to get converted to "1.088337848880613e+18". I see 1088337848880612568 right before it gets sent to Apple, but in the application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: userinfo indeed has value of "1.088337848880613e+18".

Does anybody know why this is? In the meantime, I plan on using strings instead of long values. I'm curious of anyone faced the same issue.

Edit:

Code before push:

```
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => 'default',
    );
$body['id'] = array('id' => 1088337848880612568);
$payload = json_encode($body);
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceTokenToSendTo) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));
fclose($fp);

var_dump($msg);
```

This is the var_dump of $msg:

```
string(123) " �e3i�Nίi5J/h=�
                            ��"�+�"�����V{"aps":{"alert":"Blah 07:11:31 PM","sound":"default"},"id":{"id":1088337848880612568}}"
```

And finally on iOS client side:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    NSLog(@"userInfo %@", userInfo);
```

This produces output:

```
    aps =     {
        alert = "Blah 07:10:46 PM";
        sound = default;
    };
    id =     {
        id = "1.088337848880613e+18";
    };
}
```

Comment: Provide your code that creates the payload and the code that recovers it.

Comment: Are you logging them out, inspecting them in the debugger?

Comment: @Rich Yes, I'm inspecting them both with breakpoints and on console.

Comment: @Gomfucius I wouldn't worry too much, you know the numbers are going to be `long`s so just use [`integerValue`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNumber/integerValue) (or [`unsignedIntegerValue`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNumber/unsignedIntegerValue) if you know its unsigned).

Answer (score 1):

The way the long you are sending is displayed depends on what JSON library you are using to produce the JSON String payload you are sending to Apple. For example, the JSON library I'm using converts each number to String (using java `toString ()` method), and that doesn't produce the conversion you experienced. However, when iOS passes the JSON payload to your app, it's possible it performs the conversion you experienced.

Since you are passing a JSON String (encoded to bytes) to Apple, when you pass a long instead of a String in the JSON object, all you save are the two `"` characters that surround a String but don't surround a number, so your solution of using Strings instead of long values is probably good enough. You can improve it by converting the long to a hexadecimal String (or even a higher base number), which would save a few characters compared to sending a decimal String.

After seeing your payload, instead of sending `"id":{"id":1088337848880612568}`
you could send `"id":"1088337848880612568"`, which avoids your problem and still takes less bytes than your original JSON.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm going to do in the meantime. It's weird how in the var_dump, it is still a valid long integer. But when I receive that value on the client side, it is converted to "1.088337848880613e+18".

Answer (score 0):

I would use a network sniffer like Charles Proxy to see exactly what is being received from the server.

There is some Apple code that is creating a `NSDictionary` from the data received from the server. `NSDictionary` can not contain integers, they must be represented a `NSNumber`.

The code to produce the output:

```
NSLog(@"userInfo %@", userInfo);
```

So what you are seeing is the representation the `description` method of `NSDictionary` decided to use. It is a display artifact.

Try:

```
NSNumber *idNumber = userInfo[@"id"][@"id"];
NSLog(@"idNumber: %lu", [idNumber longValue]);
```

You should get:
idNumber: 1088337848880612568

Comment: I added the NSLog code. I'm sure it's not a display artifact.

Comment: `NSLog` calls the `description` method on `NSDictionary`. The `description` can do anything it wants to, there is no guarantee as to the  display format and can change at Apple's whim.